# Ambiguity of ‘I ate food a lot’

Tags: ambiguity

Does *I ate food a lot* mean ambiguously?

1. I ate a lot of food.
2. I made a lot of chewing, biting or the other action on food.

Comment: *I ate food a lot* isn't ambiguous. It means *I often ate food*. It isn't very useful. For your second meaning we might use a verb like munch, chomp or slurp to express our eagerness, noisiness or lack of breeding.

Comment: It's not a natural expression to use. What else would you eat if not food? "I ate a lot" would be sufficient, or "I was eating a lot" if it was habitual.